# android searchview - what is the xml attribute layout and suggestionRowLayout, how to use?

Tags: android, searchview

Lets take a look at this screenshot of xml attributes i would like to make use of:
[image]

so as we can see searchview has two custom layout properties we can use to customize it .

1. layout and the other 2. suggestionRowLayout

so if i pass it a suggestionRowLayout for example, what ids do i pass to it ? for example, if a suggestions row was a simple image and text what ids should i give the text and image ?  and likewise for layout.  im searching for a way to customize the recent suggestions i have created using a SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.